# How to move the camera capture layer in UIImagePickerController

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, uiimagepickercontroller

I am trying to move the camera layer in the `UIImagePickerController` since it starts at origin (0,0). I want to move it down to origin (0,20) but I can't find anyway to access that layer and change it origin. do I have to go for the AVFoundation route?

The camera layer I am referring to is the layer where it displays what the camera is seeing right now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that in a proper way, the camera has fixed positions depending on which device you are using (http://cocoadventures.org/post/49180278364/iphone-camera-preview-dimensions).

If you want to customize it, you need to rewrite the capture view. You can do so with the AVFoundation framework (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH5-SW2)